# Python - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, string, list, append

I keep receiving this error when I try to run this code for the line "encoded.append("i")":

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

I cannot work out why the list won't append with the string. I'm sure the problem is very simple Thank you for your help.

```
def encode(code, msg):
    '''Encrypts a message, msg, using the substitutions defined in the
    dictionary, code'''
    msg = list(msg)
    encoded = []
    for i in msg:
        if i in code.keys():
            i = code[i]
            encoded.append(i)
        else:
            encoded.append(i)
            encoded = ''.join(encoded)
    return encoded
```

Comment: you have not any `"decoded.append("i")":` in your cod do you mean `"encoded.append("i")":`??

Comment: What is the logic behind `encoded = ''.join(encoded)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> encoded =["d","4"]
>>> encoded="".join(encoded)
>>> print (type(encoded))
<class 'str'> #It's not a list anymore, you converted it to string.
>>> encoded =["d","4",4] # 4 here as integer
>>> encoded="".join(encoded)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    encoded="".join(encoded)
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, int found
>>>
```

As you see, your list is converted to a string in here `"".join(encoded)`. And `append` is a method of lists, not strings. That's why you got that error. Also as you see if your `encoded` list has an element as integer, you will see `TypeError` because, you can't use `join` method on integers. Better you check your all codes again.

Answer (score 3):

You set encoded to string here:

```
encoded = ''.join(encoded)
```

And of course it doesn't have attribute 'append'.

Since you're doing it on one of cycle iteration, on next iteration you have str instead of list...

Answer (score 0):

Your string conversion line is under the `else` clause. Take it out from under the conditional, and the for loop so that it's the last thing done to `encoded`. As it stands, you are converting to a string halfway through your `for` loop:

```
def encode(code, msg):
'''Encrypts a message, msg, using the substitutions defined in the
dictionary, code'''
msg = list(msg)
encoded = []
for i in msg:
    if i in code.keys():
        i = code[i]
        encoded.append(i)
    else:
        encoded.append(i)

# after all appends and outside for loop
encoded = ''.join(encoded)
return encoded
```

Comment: If that `encoded` list has an integer element it will throw `TypeError`. It's not a solution for this question.

Comment: Nothing was stated about the type of input this function would give. This also won't work with many other types, not simply integers. The question was "why?", not, "what should this be?", thus it's perfectly reasonable, even if it's not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because of the second expression in you else statement.

```
    ''.join(encoded) returns a string that gets assigned to encoded
```

Thus encoded is now of type string.
In the second loop you have the .append(i) method in either if/else statements which can only be applied to lists and not strings.

Your .join() method should appear after the for loop right before you return it.

I apoligise if the above text does not appear right. This is my first post and I still trying to figure out how this works.